# PHP Luracast Restler adding namespace attributes to root element

Tags: xml, rest, namespaces, restler

Been having some trouble with this. How do I add namespace URL attributes to the root? I s that even possible? Any workarounds are welcomed. I have to use some of the definitions from Dublin Core, and my XML requires that the namespace is declared. i.e.

```
<metadata
  xmlns="http://example.org/myapp/"
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://example.org/myapp/ http://example.org/myapp/schema.xsd"
  xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/">

  ...
</metadata>
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is only possible by extending XmlFormat class and add the namespace to the resulting xml

However we are working on a new version of XmlFormat that will support namespaces